# Automatically send files to all bluetooth devices that are detected

Tags: windows, bluetooth, oledb

SOF, I'm trying to send a file to all Bluetooth devices that are detected by my Bluetooth on my computer but I have no idea where to start.

I tried using "BlueMiner" which can be downloaded from http://www.blueminer.net/ but when I load it up the program says: "The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." so I searched around and installed "AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe" which was downloaded from: http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=13255 however it still pops up with the same error.

Does anyone know how I can either fix this or does anyone know how to automatically detect devices and send a file to them?

I'll be putting a bounty on this as soon as it's available, **bounty addded, hopefully someone is up for the challenge**

Comment: I edited my answer to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a ready solution:

You can use [BlueMarket Lite](http://3d2f.com/programs/2-077-bluemarket-lite-download.shtml)

With BlueMarket Lite you can send pictures, text, video or audio to all bluetooth devices in range.

If you want to create your own application:

There is a nice C# Bluetooth library available in [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/)

1)In order to find all the Bluetooth devices, you should use [Asynchronous Device Discovery](http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Asynchronous%20Device%20Discovery&referringTitle=Documentation)

2)Then, you have to write all the data you want to send on the stream provided in the BluetoothClient class